# React Native, Fetch, and Dispatch: How do I access responseData within mapDispatchToProps()?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, fetch, dispatch

I'm fetching JSON Data within componentWillMount() from my "Scanner" component like so:

```
async componentWillMount() {
  const url = 'https://foo.com/products/product1.json';

  fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => this.props.dispatchProductLoad())
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

And below is my dispatch code:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return { dispatchProductLoad: () => dispatch(productLoad(SOMEDATA)) };
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Scanner);
```

Where the variable SOMEDATA should hold the value from responseData (at the moment it's not defined)

So my question is - how do I set the value of SOMEDATA to the value held in responseData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would call the action creator with the `responseData` as an argument and define your `mapDispatchToProps` function like

```
async componentWillMount() {
  const url = 'https://foo.com/products/product1.json';

  fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => this.props.dispatchProductLoad(responseData))
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return { dispatchProductLoad: (response) => dispatch(productLoad(response)) };
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Scanner);
```